# I'm so confused how airport numbering works

Tags: airport, runways

I'm so confused how airport numbering works.  If an airport has a single runway oriented 063 degrees and 243 degrees M.  What would be the runway designator?

Comment: 06/24... what is the confusing part? Rounding?

Comment: I know that runways are determined by their heading so runway 243 is like  South West and 063 would be North East.

Comment: Right, so I'm wondering what the confusing part is, how the numbers are rounded? Runways aren't identified by cardinal points (NE, NW, SW, etc).

Comment: I'm confused myself because its one of the questions on this textbook that im studying and it says the following.  "An Airport has a single runway oriented 063 degrees/243 degrees M.  What is the appropriate runway designato?"  So what i dont get is how runways are designated or i guess identified.

Comment: 06/24 like I said, runways are designated by the first two digits of the 3-digit magnetic heading. 025 = 02, 122 = 12, etc. Take a look at the duplicate question I marked.

Answer (score 6):

When a runway is at Magnetic Heading 063, it is rounded to the nearest 10° , which is 60°, so its designation is **Runway 06**

When a runway is at Magnetic Heading 243, it is rounded to the nearest 10° , which is 240°, so its designation is **Runway 24**

Since you can take off or land on a runway from either end, a single strip of asphalt will typically have two numbers, one for each end.  These two numbers will always be 180° apart, or their designations will be 18 different.

So **Runway 06/24** refers to a single runway, that you can use from either end.